# Find the probability using the cumulative distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Let X be a discrete random variable with the following distribution:

$$F(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & : x< 1 \\[0.5ex] 0.05 & : 1\leq x < 2 \\[0.5ex] 0.15 & : 2\leq x< 4 \\[0.5ex] 0.50 & : 4\leq x< 8 \\[0.5ex] 0.90 & : 8 \leq x < 16 \\[0.5ex] 1 & : 16 \leq x \end{cases}$$

a) $P(X=5)$.

b) $P(1.3<X<10)$.

c) $P(X≤5\mid X≥2)$.

For a) I did, $P(X=5) = P( 4 \leq x \leq 8) = P(X>4 \mid X\leq 8) = ($some more steps$) = 0.75/0.90$ <- im not sure about this answer.

So I am a bit confused how to proceed for b) and c). In class we only covered an example like a).

Can someone please show the steps ? Thank you!

Comment: We have $\Pr(X=5)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

From the very definition of a cumulative distribution function: $$\begin{align}F(x) ~ \mathop{:=} & ~ \mathsf P(X\leq x) \\[1ex] F(x^-) ~ = & ~ \mathsf P(X<a) \\[2ex] \therefore \mathsf P(a\leq X\leq b) ~ = & ~ \mathsf P(X\leq b) -\mathsf P(X<a) \\[1ex] = & ~ F(b^+)-F(a^-) \\[2ex] \mathsf P(a < X < b) ~ = & ~ \mathsf P(X < b) -\mathsf P(X\leq a) \\[1ex] = & ~ F(b^-)-F(a^+)\end{align}$$

Where $F(x) ~ = ~ F(x^+) ~ = ~ \lim\limits_{0<\Delta x\to 0} F(x+\Delta x)~$ and $F(x^-)~=~\lim\limits_{0<\Delta x\to 0} F(x-\Delta x)~ $  that is, watch out for the points of discontinuity.   So eg: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X\leq 8) ~ = & ~ F(8^+) \\[1ex] = & ~ F(8) \\[1ex] = & ~ 0.9\\[2ex] \mathsf P(X<8) ~ = & ~ F(8^-) \\[1ex] = & ~ 0.5\end{align}$$

---

In particular, the thing about *discrete* random variables is that it has probability masses - it is never realised at anywhere but a set of discrete points.

Here, $5$ is not one of them.   $\mathsf P(X{=}5)~=~0$

---

$$\mathsf P(X{=}x) ~=~ \begin{cases} 0.05 & : 1= x \\[0.5ex] 0.10 & : 2=x\\[0.5ex] 0.35 & : 4=x \\[0.5ex] 0.40 & : 8 =x\\[0.5ex] 0.10 & : 16 =x \\[1ex] 0 & : \textsf{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

---

For the others it is simply a case of applying the formula, and minding the discontinuities in the CDF.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(1.3< X < 10) ~= & ~ F(10^-) - F(1.3^+)
\\[2ex] \mathsf P(X\leq 5 \mid X\geq 2) ~ = & ~ \dfrac{\mathsf P(2\leq X\leq 5}{\mathsf P(2\leq X \color{silver}{< \infty})}
\\[1ex] = & ~ \dfrac{F(5^+)-F(2^-)}{1-F(2^-)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: thanks, how do i go about solving b) and c)?

Comment: Now Included. @AndrewA

Comment: thank you for that, but would you mind explaining the steps a bit ?

Comment: @AndrewA There are no steps. $~$ It is straight from the definition of a CDF.  $$\begin{align}F(x) ~ \mathop{:=} & ~ \mathsf P(X\leq x) \\[1ex] F(x^-) ~ = & ~ \mathsf P(X<a) \\[2ex] \therefore \mathsf P(a\leq X\leq b) ~ = & ~ \mathsf P(X\leq b) -\mathsf P(X<a) \\[1ex] = & ~ F(b^+)-F(a^-) \\[2ex] \mathsf P(a < X < b) ~ = & ~ \mathsf P(X < b) -\mathsf P(X\leq a) \\[1ex] = & ~ F(b^-)-F(a^+)\end{align}$$